# writing items of the list as lines to .gz in python

Tags: python, command-line, gzip

I have a list with a name `rare_seq` as follows.

```
rare_seq=['NNGGGCGACAGAC','NNGGGCGACAGAC','CCCTTGTTCAGAT]

print(len(rare_seq))=3
```

My goal is to save the items of the list `rare_seq` to `.gz` file.

**I tried the following way.**

```
f = gzip.open('rare_seq.txt.gz', 'wt')
for line in rare_seq:
    f.writelines(line)
f.close()
```

This saves the list as one line and not as three separate lines.

When I use the command `zcat` to see the content of `rare_seq.txt.gz`, I get the following output.

```
zcat rare_seq.txt.gz >> NNGGGCGACAGACNNGGGCGACAGACCCCTTGTTCAGAT
```

All the items in the list are in the same line.

**My desired output:**

```
zcat rare_seq.txt.gz >> 
NNGGGCGACAGAC
NNGGGCGACAGAC
CCCTTGTTCAGAT
```

and

```
zcat rare_seq.txt.gz | wc -l >> 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new line character `\n`

```
f = gzip.open('rare_seq.txt.gz', 'wt')
for line in rare_seq:
    f.write(line+"\n") #newline character here
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

`writelines` writes multiple lines. `write` writes one line. Thus, either

```
for line in rare_seq:
    f.write(line + "\n")
```

or

```
f.writelines(line + "\n" for line in lines)
```